# Python: Change the time on xticks for Pandas Plot

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I generate the above picture using the plot function applied to a Pandas DataFrame, e.g. `df.plot()`. My question is how can I change the xticks such that the time displayed on the xticks are `9:30:00, 11:00:00, 12:30:00, 2:00:00, 3:30:00, 4:00:00`? The index of my `df` are: `Index([09:40:00, 09:45:00, 09:50:00, 09:55:00, 10:00:00, 10:05:00, ... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always set the `xticks` parameter when you plot the series/data frame.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [10, 14, 23, 34,16,9]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
df.plot(xticks=[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5])
```

If I don't set the `xticks` the plot looks like:

[image]

and if I set the `xticks` as shown above the plot looks like:

[image]

Obviously the new `xticks` contain a value that is greater than the x values, but I'm sure you get the idea. Also, check out the pandas documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) for more information.

Comment: Great ... very simple solution.